# Pine hline @yesterdays close of an indicator

Tags: pine-script

In Pine on Tradingview I try to plot a hline at the current day which is drawn at yesterday's close of VWAP. How can I achieve this? Many thanks

Comment: Show us what you have done, so that we assist you about your specific challenges

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
dclose = security(tickerid, "D", close[1])
hline (dclose)
```

Comment: You cannot call `hline()` with `series`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. He can use plot or plotshape or plotchar instead.